# Error updating programmatically a plugin's setting

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, settings

I want to update programatically a plugin's setting:

```
public function init()
{   
     craft()->on('commerce_orders.onBeforeOrderComplete', function($event){
        // Set InvoiceNumber
        $newInvoiceNumber = $this->getSettings()->currentInvoiceNumber + 1;
        $myPlugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin( 'Ultraschall' );
        craft()->plugins->savePluginSettings( $myPlugin, 
                                              array('currentInvoiceNumber', $newInvoiceNumber ));
    });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
PHP warning
array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
/mnt/web209/c2/98/5363898/htdocs/dev.ultraschall-leinwand.de/craft/app/models/BaseModel.php(418)

417  // Is this the first time this extra attribute has been set?
418  else if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->_extraAttributeNames))
419  {
420     $this->_extraAttributeNames[] = $name;
421  }
422 
423  $this->_attributes[$name] = $value;
424  return true;
```

I have added defineSettings() and getSettingsHtml() to the Plugin and can change values via CP without problems.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the stack trace leading up to that error?  Have you ever used xDebug?  Great for figuring out stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple mistake by defining the array with the setting value.
I wrote `array('currentInvoiceNumber', $newInvoiceNumber)` instead of `array('currentInvoiceNumber' => $newInvoiceNumber)`.